# In gcc is there a way to find out which symbols are being touched by the optimizer?

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, volatile

Very diffuse question I admit - maybe you can just give me a hint in the right direction..

In a fairly large embedded C based project we observe different behavior when updating from `arm-none-eabi-gcc` `5.3.1-20160307` to `6.3.1-20170620`.

In the past similar behavior could be explained with shared variables which had been declared incorrectly and solved by declaring them `volatile`.

Now I wonder if there's a way to make GCC tell me *which* variables/symbols are touched *how* by the optimizer.

Or in other words: if someone comes to you crying 'my project does not behave well after upgrading to a new gcc and I believe I missed a `volatile` somewher - please help me!' - what would be your approach?

Comment: Smartass answer would be "All of them.", since symbols have no meaning in final binary. That's not helpful of course, but I suspect (I'm no compiler expert) that some optimizations are performed on generated instructions instead of variables or symbols.

Comment: Another possibility could be that your code exhibits undefined behaviour and you've just got away with it on the old platform.

Comment: Yes, that's true indeed. It could also be race conditions and much more. But since `volatile` had already been an issue for us, I'd like to have a way to list all `volatile` variables or a list of variables I should review on a regular basis to avoid problems which _can_ be avoided..

Comment: The first question, which things are “touched” by the optimizer is vague and ill-posed and likely does not have a good answer. The second question, how to diagnose a problem revealed by changing compiler versions, is much more concrete and actionable. I suggest editing the question, especially the title, to focus on that.